# oscommerce admin login Error

Tags: php, xampp, oscommerce

i installed this [template](http://templatewizard.eu/free-osc-template/free-oscommerce-template-luxury-p-4.html?osCsid=c55l5lrf84drmisrln18eqo121) in oscommerce

now the page after the login not displayed it shows the following error

> Warning: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object. Incorrect value given in D:\xampp\htdocs\domain\admin\login.php on line 63
>
> Error!
> Unable to determine the page link!

Function used:

```
tep_href_link('', '', 'NONSSL')
```

follwing are the version detail

- OSCommerce Online Merchant v2.3
- php version 5.4.7
- mysql version 5.0

Comment: Try to login D:\xampp\htdocs\domain\admin\index.php

Answer (score 0):

Templates are often problematic. There are several reasons why this is happening but not enough details in your question to drill down.

The first thing you should do is check the admin errorlog.  There is some data missing from the tep_href_link function.  Specifically, the page to which it is linking.  The form should be...

```
tep_href_link($page = '', $parameters = '', $connection = 'NONSSL')
```

So, your error makes perfect sense... You're not linking to anything (first parameter).

You might check this link to see if anything sounds familiar... http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/311723-unable-to-determine-the-page-linkfunction-used-tep-href-link-nonssl/